# Current time in chroot-ed environment differs from local time

Tags: c, linux, time, chroot

My `c program` in `chrooted` environment does not give  proper `current time`, how to deal with it ? Is there something to mount for it ? It is working properly in normal directory. but seems something wrong with chroot.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* puts */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime, strftime */

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];

  time (&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

  strftime (buffer,80,"date=%Y-%m-%d time=%H:%M:%S",timeinfo);
  puts (buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

normal execution:

```
./bin/binarycode
date=2013-09-23 time=20:09:02
```

chrooted execution:

```
/usr/sbin/chroot /var/rooted /bin/binarycode
date=2013-09-24 time=01:50:04
```

It seems the time is shown is 5.30 hrs. difference.

I cannot do softlink/hardlink  in this scenario. I am running this on redhat.

Comment: how do you get current time

Comment: Read man pages if you have not... http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime

Comment: Also print the raw time to see if it is same. Also, so in chroot you get correct time, in normal env not?

Comment: To investigate further, check what dynamic libs are used in both at ru time. `man ldd`, `ldd binarycode`.

Comment: Check the `chroot`'s `/etc/localtime`, is it the same (usually symbolic link) as the host's one?

Comment: The code looks ok. Compile the source after having `chroot`ed and retest.

Comment: hyde : no i cant get correct time in chroot. it shows 5.30 hrs. ahead.